# Unknown '\\' character in C++

Tags: c++, escaping

I am working on a legacy codebase & came across a '\\' character:

```
do
{
  string tmpLine;
  getline( *testcaseFilePtr, tmpLine );
  testcaseFileLineNumber++;
  if( tmpLine.size() > 0 && tmpLine[tmpLine.size() - 1] == '\\' )
  {
    readAnotherLine = true;
    tmpLine[tmpLine.size() - 1] = ' ';
  }
  else
  {
    readAnotherLine = false;
  }
  line.append( tmpLine );
} while( readAnotherLine );
```

As I have seen in gdb debugger, 'readAnotherLine' is always turning out to be false and do while is always exiting after a single iteration.

Suppose my input file looks like:

```
DEFINE xyz;
DEFINE_MODULE
{
  cout << "Example snippet" << endl;
  do_this; USER_MACRO ( do_that );
}
```

The debugger is showing that `line` string is containing one single line at a time and processing it in further steps. It is not concatenating all the lines of the input file in `line` altogether. 
Please suggest whether it is a typo or it may have some functionality.

Thanks in advance for your suggestion!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: If you have done the above provide a [MCVE] in your question.

Comment: `tmpLine[tmpLine.size() - 1] == '\\'` can be written as `tmpLine.back() == '\\'`

Comment: Start the debugger again and investigate the values of tmpLine.size() and tmpLine[tmpLine.size() - 1]. That should you give enough information why readAnotherLine is always false.

Comment: Note that it does MATTER what the input is....

Comment: And `'\\'` is the `\` character, since `\` is used as an escape for example `'\n'` is a newline - so to make a single `\`, the first one is "used up" as an escape, the second says "I want a backslash character".

Answer (score 3):

The code is looking for lines in the input file like:

```
abc\
def\
ghi
```

and will read them into a single line: `abc def ghi`.  In other words, a trailing `\` is being treated as a line continuation character.